# POM not published for submodule

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, artifactory

I noticed in my multi-module maven project that child modules' pom files are not being deployed to Artifactory. This is causing errors in dependent projects, which depend on the dependency information in the POM of the child modules, leading to errors in the Jenkins build such as: `The POM for com.myorg.services:mydomain-model:jar:1.6.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available` with subsequent compilation errors since those transitive dependencies were not downloaded.

More info:

The dependent project, a Spring Boot app, contains the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.myorg.services</groupId>
  <artifactId>mydomain-model</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Meanwhile the target project is structured as follows, with the parent POM being:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myorg.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>mydomain</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>mydomain</name>
    <description>mydomain</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>mydomain-model</module>     
    </modules>
    (...)
</project>
```

And the child POM:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myorg.services</groupId>
        <artifactId>mydomain</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.myorg.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>mydomain-model</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mydomain-model</name>
    <description>My Domain Model</description>
    (...)
</project>
```

These are the logs showing the deployment:

```
[pool-19-thread-2] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoClientBuilder - [pool-19-thread-2] Deploying artifact: https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/myorg/services/mydomain-model/1.6.1-SNAPSHOT/mydomain-model-1.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[pool-19-thread-1] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoClientBuilder - [pool-19-thread-1] Deploying artifact: https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/myorg/services/mydomain/1.14.0-SNAPSHOT/mydomain-1.14.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[main] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper - Artifactory Build Info Recorder: publish build info set to false, build info will not be published...
```

These are the logs showing the missing POM leading to compilation errors for the dependent project:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener - Downloading: https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot/com/myorg/services/mydomain-model/1.6.1-SNAPSHOT/mydomain-model-1.6.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[main] WARN org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - The POM for com.myorg.services:mydomain-model:jar:1.6.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

I checked in artifactory, and a POM file only was available for the parent module but not the child module, which only supplied a single Jar file. I was hoping to have the POM of the child module deployed to artifactory to avoid these errors/warnings. Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by switching my maven build goals from `clean verify` to `clean install`. Apparently jfrog is smart enough to build and deploy the submodule dependency via the `maven-jar-plugin` (invoked via the `verify` lifecycle phase), but it needs to have run the `maven-install-plugin` (via `install` phase) to detect and deploy to artifactory the additional artifact, namely the pom.xml.